# update date in popup form all times not only when refresh site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

How i can update date and time value in a field, when i called popup?
Because in my case the datetime django was updated on refresh.

My popup :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    PopUpHide();
});
function PopUpShow(){
    $("#popup1").show();
    $(document).keyup(function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 27)
        $("#popup1").hide();
    });
}
function PopUpHide(){
    $("#popup1").hide();
}
```

In html form popup :

```
<div class="b-popup b-popup-content" id="popup1">
  <div class="cleanuphtml-1">
    Add 'problem' item
  </div>
  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %} <input id="id_pk_post" value="1" maxlength="1" name="pk_post" type="text" /> <input id="id_post_request" value="1" maxlength="1" name="post_request" type="text" />
    <div class="cleanuphtml-2">
      <label for="id_description_post">Description:</label> 
      <textarea id="id_description_post_id" maxlength="9999" name="description_post" autofocus="" onkeyup="enableField(this.form,this.value)" type="text">
      </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="cleanuphtml-4">
      <label for="id_start_date">Start date : <input type="text" name="start_date" id="datetimepicker" />     <label>End date :</label> <input type="text" name="end_date" id="datetimepicker2"
      class="cleanuphtml-3" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="cleanuphtml-6">
      <p class="cleanuphtml-5">
        <label>Priority :</label> <select method="post" name="priority_post">
          <option value="1" id="id_priority_post" name="priority_post">
            High
          </option>
          <option value="2" id="id_priority_post" name="priority_post">
            Medium
          </option>
          <option value="3" id="id_priority_post" name="priority_post" selected="selected">
            Low
          </option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="cleanuphtml-9">
      <input type="submit" name="bttnsubmit" value="Add" onclick="window.location.href='/'" disabled="true" class="cleanuphtml-7" /> <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="PopUpHide()"
      class="cleanuphtml-8" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is with jquery called calendar :

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker()
    .datetimepicker({value:'{{ now_date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}',step:10});
```

Comment: All that code appears to be irrelevant, except for the last snippet. But you have not included the code which would be relevant, which is the part that generates the `now_date` value and passes it to the template.

Comment: Sorry but i don't know how.
Can you help? and this resolving my problem? now_date can update every minute?